# batch script to filter through hundereds of csv files in a folder and extract data to a single worksheet

Tags: filter

I am looking for help on creating a batch script which:

Asks for an input line(maybe a few words, may include wildcards, maybe just a keyword)
Goes through all the csv/xls files in a folder
Extracts the rows where that input line is found
Puts the results into a new workbook

Any help please would be great,

would love if the file is also annotated so i can learn to

Thank you in advance

Comment: this is not a free script downloading site. try yourself, if you fail, come ask here where you encountered a problem.

Comment: Hello, apologies i will upload what i have already done tonight

Comment: i have answered my own question, not sure if there is a better way though?

Comment: @Volkan Ulukut could you review my code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Echo OFF
@IF "%_Echo%" NEQ "" Echo %_Echo%
Echo xls file filter - select lines ending with the requested extension type
Echo v1.1
If "%1" NEQ "" goto -Process
Echo.
Echo Parameters
Echo  1 - Extension to search for
Echo.
Echo .csv Files in C:\Users\test\Desktop\output will be scanned for the input
Echo All matching extensions found in folder C:\Users\test\Desktop\output\*.csv
Echo   Where ********* is the filteryou entered.
Echo.
Pause
Set /p _b= "Enter Extension "
if "%_b%" NEQ "" goto -Process2
Goto :EOF

:-Process
Set _b=%1
:-Process2 
Set _Src="C:\Users\test\Desktop\output"
Echo Source %_Src%  Files 20yy-mm-dd.csv
Set _TFN="C:\Users\test\Desktop\Files\%_b%.csv"
Echo Filtered File: %_TFN%
set _HDR=
set _cnt=0
Pushd %_src%
::dir /b "C:\Users\test\Desktop\output\*.csv"
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2*" %%a IN (`dir /b "C:\Users\test\Desktop\output\**********.csv"`) DO Call :-FilterFl %%a
Echo %_cnt% Files processed
popd
pause
Goto :EOF


:-FilterFl
::Echo 1-%1 2-%2
if not exist %1 goto :-NF
if "%_HDR%" NEQ "Done" call :-DoHdr %1
Echo Processing %1
FIND /i "%_b%"<%1 >>%_TFN%
set /a _cnt=_cnt + 1
Goto :EOF
:-NF
Echo %1 is not found
goto :EOF


:-DoHdr
if "%_Debug%" NEQ "" Echo -DoHdr %1
FIND "---," <%1 >%_TFN%
set _HDR=Done
goto :EOF
```